# Is it possible to explicitly redefine a local variable

Tags: c++

I have a macro for calling a function and logging that the call was made

```
#define LogHandle(message,function) {Log(message + #function); function;}
```

The function also returns if it was successful or not, i can use a member variable like

```
#define LogHandle(message,function) {Log(message + #function); m_lastLogHandleResult = function;}
```

Then in code do

```
LogHandle("Tried to do sometheing",Func())
if(m_lastLogHandleResult) {/* more code */}
```

but this approach would be quite difficult to thread-safe

ideally id want to do something like

```
#define LogHandle(message,function) bool result; {Log(message + #function); result = function;}
```

but this causes issues if i try to use this macro twice within a scope as it's re-defining a local

is it possible to explicitly redefine a local variable? like

```
new bool result;
```

**Edit:** As comments suggest could put each call to this function within a scope `{}`, which is not a bad solution, but ideally i'd like to be able to not do this

Comment: You could explicitly create extra scopes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would implement it using a combination of macros and functions.

A macro so we can get the function "name", which calls a function passing the "name" and which returns the result to be tested.

Perhaps something like this:

```
#define LogHandle(message, function, ...) LogHandleHelper(message, function, #function, __VA_ARGS__)

template<typename R, typename F, typename... A>
R LogHandleHelper(std::string const& message, F function, std::string function_name, A&&... arguments)
{
    Log(message + function_name);
    return function(std::forward<A>(arguments)...);
}
```

Could then be used as:

```
if (LogHandle("Tried to do sometheing", Func))
{
    // Special case code here...
}
```

<sub>[Note: Untested. might need tweaks to get it working]</sub>

Comment: This is really cool, I had a similar idea, would this not need explicitly passing in the types of `R`,`F` and `...A`? AFAIK you can't template macros so I'd basically have to make a new macro for each argument type?

Comment: @Jay Maybe for `R`, the rest should be deduced automatically by the compiler. That's why I added the not-tested disclaimer. :)

Comment: @Jay The main problem is your apparent requirement to use the name of the function in the log output. Without it, the macro could be skipped.

Comment: You're right, this is really helpful thanks!

Comment: @Jay No need to accept if it's only "helpful" ;)

Answer (score 1):

### You can play preprocessor tricks to often have a unique variable name.

An example from my [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon) software:

```
#define LOCALRETURN_ATLIN_BIS_BM(Lin,Res) do {      \
  struct stackframe_stBM*prevfram_##Lin             \
    = _.__frame.stkfram_prev;                       \
  ASSERT_BM (prevfram_##Lin                         \
      && ((typedhead_tyBM *)prevfram_##Lin)->htyp   \
      == typayl_StackFrame_BM);                     \
  prevfram_##Lin->stkfram_callfun = NULL;           \
  return (value_tyBM)(Res);                         \
 } while(0)

#define LOCALRETURN_ATLIN_BM(Lin,Res) LOCALRETURN_ATLIN_BIS_BM(Lin,Res)
#define LOCALRETURN_BM(Res) LOCALRETURN_ATLIN_BM(__LINE__,(Res))
```

I would use `LOCALRETURN_BM(x)` and it gets expanded to something unique by [GNU cpp](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) using [concatenation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) and sometimes [stringizing](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringizing.html).

[RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) has similar tricks at end of 2020, and you could use some better preprocessor like [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp).

### You can also generate C++ code appropriately

You could also design your own C++ code generator, with inspiration from [SWIG](https://swig.org/) or [Qt `moc`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/why-moc.html). Tools like [ANTLR](https://antlr.org/) or [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) are then helpful. You would configure your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool (e.g. your `Makefile` for [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)). See also [GNU autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) and [GNU m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/).

With GNU cpp specifically, you can use not only `__LINE__` but [also `__COUNTER__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html#Common-Predefined-Macros)

See also [this related](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/257873/40065) answer that you could generalize to emission of C++ code. Your C++ code generator might even emit [`#line` directives](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Line-Control.html#Line-Control).